# How to keep a block of code alive in background?

Tags: ios, nstimer, background-process

I have searched for this topic bu mostly i face the restrictions of Apple. I need to once per minute control my server and ifthere is a change, fire a local notification. What i need is, how to keep timer(NSTimer) alive in background(or when the device lock is activated..) Any idea please. Thanks

Comment: Timers don't work in background. have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190919/problem-while-working-in-background-and-nstimer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reconsider the design of your app. You can't guarantee that your app will never be killed when the OS goes out hunting for memory to free up. What happens in that scenario? Push Notifications are your best bet here. First of all, you don't need to be polling your server every 60 seconds; you just fire a notification when the content you're interested in changes on the server. Secondly, the notification will be received even if your app isn't running.

The other issue is that you have to tell Apple, via your info.plist, which background modes your app supports. This is really for apps that run music or VoIP in the background. Polling a web server is not one of those supported modes. With push notifications, you also get some delegate methods you can use to handle the information passed in through the notification when the app enters the foreground.

Comment: but as far as i remember "Psuh Notifications Are never guaranteed to be received by the front side". I want to guarantee it.

Comment: If you're in airplane mode, for instance, the notification won't be received until you have a data connection again. But if you don't have a data connection, your poll-once-a-minute idea wouldn't work anyways.

Comment: Yes U are right, but the first time i create data connection i will see what  has changed

Comment: That's fine. The first time you create a data connection would be when the app is initially launched. Check to your heart's content. If the app is launched, it again makes your theory of polling in the background irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

You could do your logic in the server part and if there are changes send a Push Notification.

Answer (score 2):

My app continuously runs in the background with following piece of code.....

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{ 
  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

  backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self   selector:@selector(backgroundTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

  bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
  }];

}
```

Now do whatever you want in the **backgroundTask** method.

Comment: @Vish_Ob-j it looks reosanable but as far as i read documents Apple wouldn't let this style of code in App Store(i mean your app may be rejected)
Has this code been approved by App Store?

Comment: @ilis - I have not yet submitted my app to the appStore. But this seems to be the only possible way to keep block of code running in background...

Comment: but Apple doesn't say so. I also remember the original of this code snippet, it may be possible for locations or Vo-IP based applications(or so on).. Push notifications is better both for coding and memory management of mobile device..

Comment: yes you are right ilis. Push notifications are in fact better as far as memory management is concerned. But it depends on what is your requirement. If you are listening for an event in the background, then you should go for push notifications for sure.. Or else you can try Local Notifications also..

Comment: I sent my app to App store and activated push notifications. And it has allready need approved. [Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kempinski-macka/id583709608?l=tr&ls=1&mt=8) is its App store link.(Its interfaces arent so good, the app itself is different than the screenshots:)